# How do I stay in the same desktop when I switch to a full screen app?

Tags: macos, dock, desktop, fullscreen

When I switch to a full screen mode app in OS X Lion, it automatically switches to Desktop 1. I prefer to automatically switch back to the Desktop that I was in before I switched to the full screen app. I tried configuring the app for "All Desktops" and "None" by right clicking on the app in the Dock and choosing "Options". Both resulted in the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: When I turn an application to full screen, that application gets its own desktop, and I see that desktop, not the first desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set it to go back to the last Desktop you were in, but you can set it to go to a specific Desktop when you exit full screen.

Just move the application in windowed mode to the desktop you want, right-click the app in the Dock and set to "This Desktop". Whenever you come out of full screen, it will always go into windowed mode in that particular desktop.